# Как компактно написать?

Tags: java, android

Дайте совет, как можно сжать этот код в обьеме? У меня 4 метода, которые +/- делают одно и тоже, но не могу догадаться как его отрефакторить...

Код выполняет анимацию между переходами. Я думал сделать класс и наследовать, потом думал как интерфейс сделать, потом думал просто вынести слушатель из всех 4 методов и как-то проверками выполнять то что нужно.

Но как-то все очень криво мне это придумывается))

```
public static void offRegistrationFrame(final Context context) {
    registrationFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    registrationFrame.setAlpha(1);

    Animation registrationFrameOff = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.alpha_frame_off);
    registrationFrameOff.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            registrationFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loginFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Animation loginFrameOn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.open_next);
            loginFrame.startAnimation(loginFrameOn);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    registrationFrame.startAnimation(registrationFrameOff);
}

public static void offLoginFrame(final Context context) {
    mainFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mainFrame.setAlpha(1);

    Animation loginFrameOff = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.alpha_frame_off);
    loginFrameOff.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            mainFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            forgotPasswordFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Animation loginFrameOn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.open_next);
            forgotPasswordFrame.startAnimation(loginFrameOn);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    mainFrame.startAnimation(loginFrameOff);
}

public static void offForgotPasswordFrame(final Context context){
    forgotPasswordFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    forgotPasswordFrame.setAlpha(1);

    Animation loginFrameOff = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.close_next);
    loginFrameOff.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            forgotPasswordFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mainFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Animation loginFrameOn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.alpha_frame_on);
            mainFrame.startAnimation(loginFrameOn);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    forgotPasswordFrame.startAnimation(loginFrameOff);
}

public static void goBackToReg(final Context context){
    loginFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    loginFrame.setAlpha(1);

    Animation registrationFrameOff = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.close_next);
    registrationFrameOff.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            loginFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            registrationFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Animation loginFrameOn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.alpha_frame_on);
            registrationFrame.startAnimation(loginFrameOn);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    loginFrame.startAnimation(registrationFrameOff);
}
```

Спасибо за идеи!

Comment: Анимация в Static методах в которых подается Context и View), эхххх.. ну ок.
У вас явно повторяющийся конструктор для анимаций, используйте абстракцию. Будет красиво выглядеть, сейчас добавлю код.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei вы ж знаете, что я новичок и это моя первая работа... Если есть совет, я рад послушать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас и в самом деле почти идентичный код в методах. Он отличается только видом анимаций и вьюхами, на кои она применяется и кои становятся видимыми/невидимыми.

Засим вам вот это всё и надо передать в один общий метод. Типа как-то так:

```
public static void offRegistrationFrame(
                            final Context context,
                            int startAnimationRes, int endAnimationRes,
                            View firstView, View secondView) {
    firstView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    firstView.setAlpha(1);

    Animation startAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, startAnimationRes);
    startAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            firstView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            secondView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Animation endAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, endAnimationRes);
            secondView.startAnimation(endAnimation);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    firstView.startAnimation(startAnimation);
}
```

Comment: Да, но эти методы у меня вызываются из других классов и получается не совсем удобно передавать вьюхи в эти методы из других классов...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, должен признаться, что не понял вашей проблемы.

Comment: В итоге сделал что то общее между вашим советом и @Shwarz Andrei... Сделал класс обертку, чтоб не использовать те реализации которыми не пользуюсь, немного поменял взаимодействие и привел все к одной функции так как вы посоветовали и передаю ей набор переменных завернутых в классе

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, думаю, лишним не будет, если вы своё итоговое решение отдельным ответом выложите)

Comment: Выложил. Может тогда ради интереса гляните, может, что не так...)

Answer (score 2):

Если увидеть больше, то я уверен что, можно оптимизировать ваш код, намного сильней. А если иметь, то что имеем, то самый простой и очевидный способ:

Создаем абстрактный класс: CustomAnimationListener.class

```
abstract class CustomAnimationListener implements Animation.AnimationListener{

View v1,v2;

public CustomAnimationListener(final View v1, final View v2) {
    this.v1 = v1;
    this.v2 = v2;
}
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(final Animation animation) {

}
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(final Animation animation) {
    v1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    v2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(final Animation animation) {}
}
```

А дальше всё аналогично вашему коду:

```
public static void offRegistrationFrame(final Context context){
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.alpha);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new CustomAnimationListener(v1, v2){
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(final Animation animation) {
            Animation loginFrameOn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.open_next);
            forgotPasswordFrame.startAnimation(loginFrameOn);
        }
    });
 anim.startAnimation(registrationFrameOff);
}
```

Хотя на самом делу это не очень вариант, так как, код должен быть легко поддерживаемый и читаемый, а у вас до этого момента, раз вы закидываете Context в static метода и подаете в него глобальные View, уже что-то пошло не так.
В хорошем виде нужно и советую доделать с помощью абстракции такой вид:

```
private void offRegistrationFrame(View v1, View v2, Animation animEnd){
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new CustomAnimationListener(v1, v2, animEnd){});
    v2.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Будут три таких коротких метода, и предварительно нужно вынести создание animEnd, так как анимации всего две на появление и исчезновение, как я понял...
Такой код будет быстрей работать и занимать меньше памяти, вы словите в будущем гораздо меньше ошибок и он будет намного легче поддерживаться и читаться.

Comment: А зачем описывать реализацию в абстрактном классе для метода `onAnimationEnd` если при вызове этого метода мы все равно переопределяем его...?

Comment: Следуя первому примеру я не вижу, чтоб вы где то запускали анимацию... Вы получаете обьект `anim` ставите ему `setAnimationListener` , но в конце же должна быть строка `.startAnimation()`, а то анимация так и не запуститься...

Comment: Для того, чтоб не переопределять методы которые вы не используйте. Добавил.

Comment: Не совсем понял насчет первого... Мой вопрос был в том, что зачем мы описываем реализацию метода `onAnimationEnd` который находится в абстрактном классе `CustomAnimationListener` , если все равно потом когда мы им будем пользоваться мы будем переопределять реализацию... Зачем тогда ее описание v1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    v1.setAlpha(1f);

Answer (score 1):

В итоге сделал так

```
public class UtilForAnim {

private static int currentFrame;
private static FrameLayout frameRegistration, frameLogin, frameForgotPassword, frameMain;

private Context context;

public UtilForAnim(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public UtilForAnim initFrames(FramesWrapper frames) {
    frameRegistration = frames.getFrameRegistration();
    frameLogin = frames.getFrameLogin();
    frameForgotPassword = frames.getFrameForgotPassword();
    frameMain = frames.getFrameMain();
    return this;
}

private void changeFrameWithAnim(final AnimationInstance ai){
    setVisibility(ai.getFirstView());
    Animation registrationFrameOff = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, ai.getStartAnimationRes());
    registrationFrameOff.setAnimationListener(new CustomAnimationListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(final Animation animation) {
            changeFrameVisibility(ai.getFirstView(), ai.getSecondView());
            Animation loginFrameOn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, ai.getEndAnimationRes());
            ai.getSecondView().startAnimation(loginFrameOn);
        }
    });

    ai.getFirstView().startAnimation(registrationFrameOff);
}

private void ternOnForgotFrame() {
    AnimationInstance animationInstance = new AnimationInstance(frameMain, frameForgotPassword, R.anim.alpha_frame_off, R.anim.open_next);
    changeFrameWithAnim(animationInstance);
    setCurrentFrame(States.FORGOT_FRAME);
}

public void setCurrentFrame(int state) {
    currentFrame = state;
}

public void ternOnRegFrame() {
    AnimationInstance animationInstance = new AnimationInstance(frameLogin, frameRegistration, R.anim.close_next,R.anim.alpha_frame_on);
    changeFrameWithAnim(animationInstance);
    setCurrentFrame(States.REGISTRATION_FRAME);
}

public boolean switcherFrame(int frameWhichYouNeed) {
    if (frameWhichYouNeed == States.PREVIOUS_FRAME) {
        return ternOnPreviousFrame();
    }

    switch (frameWhichYouNeed) {
        case States.FORGOT_FRAME:
            ternOnForgotFrame();
            break;
        case States.REGISTRATION_FRAME:
            ternOnRegFrame();
            break;
        case States.LOGIN_FRAME:
            ternOnLogInFrame();
            break;
    }
    return false;
}

private void ternOnLogInFrame() {

    switch (currentFrame){
        case States.REGISTRATION_FRAME:
            AnimationInstance animationInstance = new AnimationInstance(
                    frameRegistration, frameLogin, R.anim.alpha_frame_off, R.anim.open_next);
            changeFrameWithAnim(animationInstance);
            setCurrentFrame(States.LOGIN_FRAME);
            break;
        case States.FORGOT_FRAME:
            AnimationInstance animationInstance1 = new AnimationInstance(
                    frameForgotPassword, frameMain, R.anim.close_next, R.anim.alpha_frame_on);
            changeFrameWithAnim(animationInstance1);
            setCurrentFrame(States.LOGIN_FRAME);
            break;
    }
}

public static int getCurrentFrame() {
    return currentFrame;
}

@Nullable
private Boolean ternOnPreviousFrame() {
    switch (getCurrentFrame()) {
        case States.FORGOT_FRAME:
            ternOnLogInFrame();
            return false;
        case States.LOGIN_FRAME:
            ternOnRegFrame();
            return false;
        case States.REGISTRATION_FRAME:
            return true;
    }
    return true;
}

private void setVisibility(View frameToSetVisibly) {
    frameToSetVisibly.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    frameToSetVisibly.setAlpha(1);
}

private void changeFrameVisibility(View whichIsGone, View whichIsVisible) {
    whichIsGone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    whichIsVisible.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}
```